# difference between "Python" file and "python2.7" file on macOS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I have a macOS Sierra 10.12.3 and I have installed Python 2.7.13 by downloading it from the official Python site.
When I type `which python` I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7/bin/python`. The `python` file referenced in this result is a shortcut for `python2.7` file located in the same directory.

I'm wondering what is the difference between `Python` (with the capital "P") file located in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7` and the one mentioned above? Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but I strongly recommend that you install python with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer).

Answer (score 0):

`python` is alias name for current python binary. It's symlink to some version of python binary called `Python`. Something like

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7/Python`

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/3.5/Python`

Currently code for 2.7+ and 3.0+ may conflict (like use `print(x)` instead of `print x` or `range` for generators instead `xrange` in 2.7. etc).

So if your scripts are not ported for newest version you will probably catch a lot of errors while executing

`python my_cool_script.py`

because you wrote code for 2.7 and after installation you trying to execute it with 3.5 version. So you can change symlink back to `Version/2.7/Python` and execute the same command and it will work like you code it and version conflict will be solved.

Comment: I don't have Python 3.x installed at all, but thanks for the answer

Comment: it's made in case you want to install it. Same mechanism works for every installed programs/frameworks/libs